# Reset sound drivers

Tags: sound, skype

I fixed a sound problem in skype with [this guide on Linux Tips & Tricks](http://linuxtipstricks.wordpress.com/2009/04/04/how-to-permanently-fix-skype-audio-problem-in-ubuntu/)

But now I have no sound button in the system tray. How to undo what I did following the tutorial?

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this link: http://www.geekyboy.com/archives/664

In summary, in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, I replaced

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

with

```
load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=0 tsched=0
```